# Want to up-vote someone i down-voted him for bad reasons?

Tags: discussion, downvoting, up-votes

I am sorry, i don't even know if this is the right place to ask the question,
but `i down-voted someone for revenge` as i think that he down-voted me because i rejected his edit to one of my questions as he thinks my English sucks as it's not my native language and i think he is right.
And i don't care anymore about who did this or why now i want to up-vote him as i am somehow felt guilty towards him but i can't up-vote him so if there are any admin there i want him if he like to `undo these silly things i did` and thanks.

Comment: Post a link to the question or answer your down voted. We all get both up votes and down votes, don't take the down votes personally, jut try to improve your question or answer or ask for clarification of the down vote.

Comment: 1- http://askubuntu.com/questions/603478/unable-to-install-ubuntu-14-lts-64bit-on-lenovo-ideapad-s205
2- http://askubuntu.com/questions/603952/gpt-adding-windows-and-dual-booti
3- http://askubuntu.com/questions/601744/where-do-deleted-files-go-in-ubuntu/601745#601745
The guy name is @Organic Marble

Comment: You may not have down voted Organic Marble as he edited some of those questions, not asked or answered =(

Answer (score 1):

Mods can't actually see who you voted for. I'd suggest not doing it again.

In theory you could take back your downvote, and turn it into an upvote if someone edited the post, but of course, someone needs to find something to edit.